# apache webserver don't manage static files

Tags: mysql, apache, server, crm, erp

I'm installing Dolibarr istance for my company. I installed it with LAMP. Now, on localhost everything works fine and i have the classic interface.[image]

After this. i Build a virtualhost like this, to point the site on erp.varesenext.it

```
              <VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName erp.varesenext.it
    ServerAlias www.erp.varesenext.it
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dolibarr1/

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
```

```
    # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Then, i fix the /etc/hosts file:

```
             40.71.186.112        erp.varesenext.it
```

to point that site on my webserver.

All works fine, but when i go to my browser, it shows me only text, without the app inter face...like this[image]

Any help??

This is the folder dolibarr1 inside /var/www/html/dolibarr1

```
                   drwxrwxr-x 11 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 accountancy
                   drwxrwxr-x  9 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 adherents
                   drwxrwxr-x  5 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 admin
                   drwxrwxr-x  4 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 api
                    drwxrwxr-x  2 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 asterisk
                   drwxrwxr-x  2 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 barcode
                   drwxrwxr-x  4 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 bookmarks
                    drwxrwxr-x 19 www-data www-data   4096 Mar 11 22:40 build
                   drwxrwxr-x  9 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 cashdesk
                   drwxrwxr-x  4 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 categories
                   -rwxrwxr-x  1 www-data www-data 213138 Feb  2 01:24 ChangeLog
                   drwxrwxr-x  7 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 comm
                   drwxrwxr-x  5 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 commande
                  -rwxrwxr-x  1 www-data www-data   2072 Jan 24 13:32 composer.json
                  -rwxrwxr-x  1 www-data www-data  63478 Jan 24 13:32 composer.lock
                   drwxrwxr-x 16 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 compta
                   drwxrwxr-x  2 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 10:09 conf
                    drwxrwxr-x  4 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 contact
                    drwxrwxr-x  5 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 contrat
                    -rwxrwxr-x  1 www-data www-data  35147 Jan 24 13:32 COPYING
                   -rwxrwxr-x  1 www-data www-data   9700 Jan 24 13:32 COPYRIGHT
                    drwxrwxr-x 14 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 core
                    drwxrwxr-x  4 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 cron
                   drwxrwxr-x  2 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 custom
                   drwxrwxr-x  8 www-data www-data   4096 Mar 11 22:35 dev
                     drwxrwxr-x  5 www-data www-data   4096 Mar 11 22:35 doc
                   -rwxrwxr-x  1 www-data www-data    610 Jan 24 13:32 Dockerfile
                  -rwxrwxr-x  1 www-data www-data   6359 May 30 09:44 document.php
                   drwxrwxr-x 14 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 11:07 documents
                    drwxrwxr-x  7 www-data www-data   4096 Jan 24 17:47 dolibarr-4.0.4
                     drwxrwxr-x  6 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 don
                     drwxrwxr-x  5 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 ecm
                       drwxrwxr-x  5 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 expedition
                       drwxrwxr-x  7 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 expensereport
                        drwxrwxr-x  3 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 exports 
                       drwxrwxr-x  3 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 externalsite
                      -rwxrwxr-x  1 www-data www-data   2238 May 30 09:44 favicon.ico 
                      drwxrwxr-x  6 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 fichinter
                      -rwxrwxr-x  1 www-data www-data  17147 May 30 09:44 filefunc.inc.php
                        drwxrwxr-x  9 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 fourn
                     drwxrwxr-x  3 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 ftp
                      drwxrwxr-x  4 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 holiday
                      drwxrwxr-x  5 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 hrm
                     drwxrwxr-x  3 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 imports
                    drwxrwxr-x 26 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 includes
                   -rwxrwxr-x  1 www-data www-data  26543 May 30 09:44 index.php
                  drwxrwxr-x  7 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 install
                 -rwxrwxr-x  1 www-data www-data     91 Jan 24 13:32 INSTALL
                drwxrwxr-x 83 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 langs
                   drwxrwxr-x  3 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 livraison
                drwxrwxr-x  4 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 loan
                     drwxrwxr-x  3 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 mailmanspip
                 -rwxrwxr-x  1 www-data www-data  97173 May 30 09:44 main.inc.php
             drwxrwxr-x  5 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 margin
            -rwxrwxr-x  1 www-data www-data  11689 May 30 09:44 master.inc.php
             drwxrwxr-x  3 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 multicurrency
             drwxrwxr-x  6 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 opensurvey
             drwxrwxr-x  5 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 paybox
             drwxrwxr-x  5 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 paypal
             drwxrwxr-x  4 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 printing
              drwxrwxr-x 10 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 product
              drwxrwxr-x  8 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 projet
             drwxrwxr-x 13 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 public
            -rwxrwxr-x  1 www-data www-data   6086 Jan 24 13:32 README-FR.md
             -rwxrwxr-x  1 www-data www-data   6953 Mar  7 14:46 README.md
              drwxrwxr-x  3 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 resource
             -rwxrwxr-x  1 www-data www-data    115 May 30 09:44 robots.txt
               drwxrwxr-x 15 www-data www-data   4096 Jun  5  2015 scripts
               drwxrwxr-x  9 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 societe
               drwxrwxr-x  5 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 supplier_proposal
               drwxrwxr-x  2 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 support
               drwxrwxr-x  5 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 theme
            drwxrwxr-x  6 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 user
           -rwxrwxr-x  1 www-data www-data   6936 May 30 09:44 viewimage.php
             drwxrwxr-x  3 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 webservices
              drwxrwxr-x  3 www-data www-data   4096 May 30 08:52 websites
```

Comment: If you look in your browser console, you may see that a lot of resources are error 404, can you check what they are?

Comment: 404 not found for all css, js, and image files

Comment: What URL are they using?

Comment: If the files exist, check that www-data:www-data has at least read access to the files and directories that these files are in.

Comment: different urls, 
  
 http://erp.varesenext.it/dolibarr1/includes/jquery/plugins/tablednd/jquery.tablednd.0.6.min.js?version=5.0.0                        http://erp.varesenext.it/dolibarr1/core/js/jnotify.js?version=5.0.0

Comment: the file exists in the folder of dolibar that is inside /var/www/html/dolibarr1

Comment: You say there in a folder dolibar - should that have a 1 on the end to match the url being accessed? (with the extra r as well)

Comment: yes, sorry , the folder is called dolibarr1, it isn't this.

Comment: Can you do a `ls -l` in the dolibarr1 directory and add it to your post.

Comment: done as you said @NigelRen